# Flow formula is not working

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, screen-flow, process

I have a process builder I wanted to convert this process builder in to flow: In PB I have formula as

```
ISCHANGED([Opportunity].OwnerId ) 
&& CONTAINS([Opportunity].Name, 'SQO') 
&& PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].Owner.Profile.Name) = 'Sales -Tributary Sales Resources'
```

If I use same formula I get error as

> The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '=''

When I convert this formula in flow it looks like this:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED([{!$Record.OwnerId}),
    CONTAINS({!$Record.Name}[Opportunity].Name, 'SQO'),
    ISPRIORVALUE({!$Record.{!$Record.Owner.Profile.Name}}) && {!$Record.Owner.Profile.Name} == 'Sales - Tributary Sales Resources'
)
```

I get the error

> The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '='

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the below formula for the flow as per your process builder formula.

```
AND( 
    ISCHANGED({!$Record.OwnerId}), 
    CONTAINS({!$Record.Name}, 'SQO'), 
    PRIORVALUE({!$Record..Owner.Profile.Name}) = 'Sales - Tributary Sales Resources' 
    )
```

In flow == operator does not work. only you need to use the = operator to check equality.